# Password char в windows form. С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Не понимаю как правильно сделать чекбокс на показ пароля если отмечен.
Есть вот такой код

```
 private void cbShowPass_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (cbShowPass.Checked)
        {
            tbPass.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        } else
        {
            tbPass.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        }
    }
```

Именно этот код ведет себя странно. Суть такая, форма стартует я вввожу пароль и он показывается не скрытым, ставлю чекбокс он не скрытый.
Очищаю поле, опять ввожу пароль, в этот раз он уже скрыт, по клику на чекбокс он показывается.
В чем моя ошибка?
И как сделать свои значки скрытого пароля? В свойствах текстбокса я поставил "*" такой символ. Если отрабатывать код выше, то там точки скрывают пароль.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Обычный WinForms

Comment: Добавил в метки.

Comment: А если у поля выставлять PasswordChar = '\0' или PasswordChar = '*', в зависимости от состояния checkbox'a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновление 2**
UseSystemPasswordChar - использовать **системный** символ пароля. В случае если вам нужно свой, достаточно кода(изменил код оригинального ответа)

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.PasswordChar = checkBox1.Checked ? '*' : '\0';
    }
```

**Обновление 1**

У Вас всё корректно работает. Изначально режим пароля отключён. 
if(checkbox.Checked) - если чекбокс "чекнут", то UseSystemPasswordChar = false, т.е. отключить. Он итак был отключён, далее, при снятии галочки, свойство Checked становится false и в этом случае Вы ставите UseSystemPassword = true.

**Оригинальный ответ**

Скорее всего что-то не то с начальными настройками, сделайте следующее для проверки:

1. Добавьте пустую форму для тестирования, на ней
2. Добавьте новый чекбокс на форму
3. Добавьте новый тексбокс на форму
4. Дважды кликните по чекбоксу и добавьте такой код, переименовав контролы под свои имена

   ```
   private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = checkBox1.Checked;
   }
   ```
5. Запустите созданную форму.
6. Введите что-либо в текстбокс
7. Поставьте галочку на чекбокс
8. Снимите галочку

У меня всё работает. Если у вас не заработает обновите версию .netframework (можно просто поставить последнюю visual studio). Если работает, значит что-то ещё в Вашем проекте влияет на вывод в текстбокс.

Приведённые действия корректно работают. Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017(ставил неделю назад)

Comment: Работает но наоборот:)
Получается если стоит галочка, то пароль скрыт, если галочку снять то пароль открыт.

Comment: @Petr поставьте код, `textBox1.UseSystemPasswordChar = !checkBox1.Checked;`.

Comment: @Petr для использования оригинального примера убедитесь, что начальное значение `UseSystemPasswordChar` false и начальное значение `checkbox` тоже false(`checkbox.Checked == false`)

Comment: @Petr обновил ответ

Comment: Все, разобрался:) Спасибо.

Comment: @Petr Пожалуйста, ещё добавил про символ.